# Keywordize with Java Maps

Tags: clojure

I'm using Nashorn in my Clojure application. When evaluating a javascript code it returns a ScriptObjectMirror which in turn implements the java.util.Map interface.

I'm trying to keywordize the maps keys using clojure.walk/keywordize-keys, however it seems to have no effect in maps other than IPersistentMap.

So I tried the follwing code:

```
(into {}
  (for [[k v] eval-result]
      [(keyword k) v]))
```

However it doesn't work recursively. Any idea on how to keywordize java maps? Shouldn't clojure.walk/keywordize-keys work with the Map interface?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way

```
(defn keywordize [object]
  (if (instance? java.util.Map object)
      (into {}
            (for [[k v] object]
                [(keyword k) (keywordize v)]))
      object
  )
)
```